# image in perspective transformation doesn't shifts to right and up

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement the following function which transforms an image by using 4 source point that i decide. the problem is that the image always shifts to right and up then it supposed to .

In the function the points are

```
luc=left up column
luw= left up row
ldc=left down column 
# and so on...
```

What i do in this project:

1. I get an image.
2. I resize the image so i  could see all the image in `cv2.show()` (the image size changed `0.25` of the original image ) .
3. I choose with a mouse 4 points in the resized image (but duplicates the coordinates by 4 that will show like the original image ) and puts the coordinates in the Perspective transform .

I would like to know what i need to fix in my code that it could work right.

Thanks in advance :)

code:

```
import cv2;
import numpy as np;
import os;
import csv;
import tkinter as tk;
from tkinter import messagebox;
def get_mouse_position(event,x,y,flags,param):
## Gets mouse position in the image

 if event ==  cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    column,width = x,y;

    text1.delete(1.0,tk.END);
    text2.delete(1.0,tk.END);

    text1.insert(1.0,str(x*4));
    text2.insert(1.0,str(y*4));

def bilinear_transformation():
##Calculates bilinear transformation and show the transform image
 img=cv2.imread('image1.jpg');
 width,column,ch=img.shape;

 luc=int(luc_e.get());
 luw=int(luw_e.get());
 ldc=int(ldc_e.get());
 ldw=int(ldw_e.get());
 ruc=int(ruc_e.get());
 ruw=int(ruw_e.get());
 rdc=int(rdc_e.get());
 rdw=int(rdw_e.get());

 src_point=np.float32([[luw,luc],[ldw,ldc],[ruw,ruc],[rdw,rdc]]);
 dst_point=np.float32([[0,0],[width,0],[0,column],[width,column]]);
 matrix=cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_point,dst_point);

 new_img=cv2.warpPerspective(img,matrix,(column,width));
 new_img=cv2.resize(new_img, (0,0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25);
 cv2.imshow("Perspective transformation",new_img);
 cv2.setMouseCallback("Perspective transformation",get_mouse_position);
```

I expect that if i choose the 4 edges of the paper i would see in the new image that the image edges are the points that i chose .

Comment: Try printing your points to be sure you are capturing what you think you are.

Comment: I print my points and i see that they are exactly .where they are supposed to be.I would like to know where the problem can be or is there something in the code ?

Comment: Perhaps post your image and points so others can try your code

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/KxwhZr8  =  the image  . And the locations are  left up (row,column) = (848,536) ,  left down (row,column)=(3088,536) , right up (row,column) = (812,3840) , right down (row, column ) = (3068,3840)

Comment: If row means y and column means x, then I believe that  cv2.getPerspectiveTransform requires points listed as (x,y), not (y,x)

Comment: See also https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

Comment: Really appreciate your advice. It works really well . The problem was that I mistaken between them . Thank you